# Using <object> for SVG to and inline css from HTML to edit fill

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

I want to replace a flash object that uses a single swf file (map of USA) and uses flash vars identified in the html to dynamically change colors of different states. Using a single file for multiple pages.

I've created an SVG file with each state having an ID name of it's two letter state abbreviation. What I'd like to do is import this using  or , then using inline CSS on the HTML page manipulate the SVG image and adjust the fill of certain items.

Inline CSS within the SVG file (or referencing an external CSS file from within the SVG file) will not meet my desire of having one image file to be used on many pages – like the original swf.

Beaten my head against the monitor for a few days now trying a bunch of jQuery and javascript stuff, but sadly I am not proficient enough in js to make this work on my own.

Thanks for any advise or help!

Comment: Can you post the code of what you have tried.

Comment: I've attempted every method of placing an SVG that google can suggest, using <img>, <object>, <iframe> ... If i draw my vector SVG in the html I can alter the styles within the same page, but that will result in a simple 100 line file becoming a 4000 line file and blowing file size through the roof.. I am thinking at this moment it is not possible to send variables or parameters to a SVG from the html file you're embedding it from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't feel browser support is yet where I need for this question to be answered. What I ended up doing is creating the flash version http://ryanhollingsworth.com/test/map.html

How it works, you embed the swf and use flashvars to assign values to two arrays, color array and state array. Result is I can use the same swf on multiple pages, with different colors and have different states colored differently.

SVG will catch up, soon i hope :)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I completely understood what you are asking for. I think you have an SVG image with all the states of the USA and try to use (inline) CSS to "highlight" one or more of those states?

If so, traditional methods will not work. JavaScript is not able to modify images, neither is CSS, AFAIK. The only way that I would know is to read in the SVG more or less byte for byte and base64-encode it after you have altered the image via JavaScript, then create an Image and set the source using a [data URI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/data_URIs).

There are a couple of encryptors in the Web. I suggest looking into the [JSXGraph](http://jsxgraph.uni-bayreuth.de/wp/), specifically the *JSXCompressor* or something of that nature. Also there are some libraries to edit images, like [PNGlib](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/libpng.html), although it is not quite what you are looking for. Try Google. But honestly, I don't feel like googling hours for you now by myself...

Hope I at least gave you a kick into the right direction.

Comment: Yeah it's messy. In flash this is super simple and a lot cleaner.. simple forin loop and done, but anyways... an SVG is a data file. Within the actual file you can apply mouse over effects, and color changes, all sorts of nifty stuff. You can even assign clickthrough URLs for specific regions of the SVG and do animation stuff. proof of concept: http://ryanhollingsworth.com/test/facebook.svg mouse over the top portion, it'll turn red. Anyways, I want to have one file on multiple pages and have it render differently .. same functionality as a flash file

Comment: @RyanHollingsworth Now I got you. Gotta say that I'm not that much of a computer graphics artist and didn't even know that that was possible with SVGs. I always thought people did that with the `map` tag in HTML, especially since I've seen it as I browsed the source code back in the days... But that was years ago. I guess I won't be a great help. Though just googling something, I found [this](http://www.schepers.cc/w3c/svg/params/ref.html). Don't know if SVG supports parameters... Plus I think you've already considered that anyways.

Comment: thanks, I think for this idea of mine i will have to wait for browsers to catch up with me ... logically I see SVG support increasing and becoming the standard for icons and such, given the multiple DPI screens we now have to design for! thanks for the help!

Comment: @RyanHollingsworth You're right, they'll probably become more popular especially if you can script them. Makes a splendid playground for graphics artists and programmers.

Answer (score 0):

[Here's something in SVG](http://games.co.za/united-states-svg.html) that seems similar to what you're trying to do. The states change colour as you mouse over them. I'm sure you could learn from it.

Comment: Thanks, I've looked at this before, but it is in the same ball park as my previous situation.. the styles and javascript are coded in the SVG (download it, open in and html editor) I think it is presently not possible to accomplish what I am trying to do.. oh well!

Answer (score 0):

You can most probably use <object> with URL fragment parameter passing. See [this example](http://xn--dahlstrm-t4a.net/images/textcorner.svg#text=custom%20text).

What you're asking for is basically [SVG Parameters](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVGParamPrimer/) (note: spec is a working draft, there are no known implementations and the syntax will likely change). There is a [script fallback solution](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVGParamPrimer/param.js) used by the demos in that spec that might be helpful.